# Why are there so many 'vimrcs'?

Tags: vim

I wanted to make my `vim` settings permanent and I looked for `vimrc` file. Finally I found out that there was not a `vimrc` in my *home directory* and I should creat one. But when I searched for `vimrc`(in /) by doing:

```
sudo find -iname "vimrc" | grep vimrc
```

I got:

> ./snap/core/6964/usr/share/vim/vimrc
>
> ./snap/core/6818/etc/vim/vimrc
>
> ./snap/core/6818/usr/share/vim/vimrc
>
> ./snap/core/6673/etc/vim/vimrc
>
> ./snap/core/6673/usr/share/vim/vimrc
>
> ./snap/core18/970/etc/vim/vimrc
>
> ./snap/core18/970/usr/share/vim/vimrc
>
> ./snap/core18/941/etc/vim/vimrc
>
> ./snap/core18/941/usr/share/vim/vimrc
>
> ./snap/core18/782/etc/vim/vimrc
>
> ./snap/core18/782/usr/share/vim/vimrc
>
> ./usr/share/vim/vimrc
>
> ./etc/vim/vimrc

I want to know:

- Why are there so many `vimrcs`?
- Can they be edited in order to make changes in `vim` permanent?

Comment: Vim is installed by default with the snap core so it has it own settings by default, as well as Ubuntu itself has vim installed.  Those vimrc files are defaults.  If you want to make the settings permanent for you all you should have to do is create a vimrc file in your home folder as `~/.vimrc` that you can set all the default settings you want from there.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have more then 1 vim on your system.

> ./snap/core/6964/usr/share/vim/vimrc

control it with `snap list` and `dpkg -l | grep vim`